# Prism.js html examples in React

Tags: reactjs, prism.js

So I'm switching an internal style guide for a site we're working on from regular html to use reactjs. I've got example code and I'm using highlighting with prism.js. The highlighting seems to work fine, but line breaks don't. Even putting in br tags after every line has no effect. Anyone have any thoughts on this?
Just some example code:

```
var Example = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div class="highlight">
              <pre>
                 <code class="language-markup">
                     &lt;label class=&quot;select&quot;&gt;
                     &lt;select class=&quot;selector&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;option value=&quot;1&quot;&gt;1&lt;/option&gt;
                            &lt;option value=&quot;2&quot;&gt;2&lt;/option&gt;
                            &lt;option value=&quot;3&quot;&gt;3&lt;/option&gt;
                            &lt;option value=&quot;4&quot;&gt;4&lt;/option&gt;
                            &lt;option value=&quot;5&quot;&gt;5&lt;/option&gt;
                         &lt;/select&gt;
                     &lt;/label&gt;
                 </code>
             </pre>
         </div>
    );
  }      
});

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

When it renders it looks like this.

```
<label class="select"><select class="selector"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></label>
```

But I expect it to look like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="highlight">
                  <pre>
                     <code class="language-markup">
                         &lt;label class=&quot;select&quot;&gt;
                         &lt;select class=&quot;selector&quot;&gt;
                                &lt;option value=&quot;1&quot;&gt;1&lt;/option&gt;
                                &lt;option value=&quot;2&quot;&gt;2&lt;/option&gt;
                                &lt;option value=&quot;3&quot;&gt;3&lt;/option&gt;
                                &lt;option value=&quot;4&quot;&gt;4&lt;/option&gt;
                                &lt;option value=&quot;5&quot;&gt;5&lt;/option&gt;
                             &lt;/select&gt;
                         &lt;/label&gt;
                     </code>
                 </pre>
             </div>
```

Anyone know of a way to preserve the line breaks?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/ohwz5ry2/

Comment: Almost, but that's more of a workaround than I'd prefer.  If I don't have to add all the line breaks, that would be ideal.

Comment: React collapses space by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just code like this:

```js
var Example = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div class="highlight">
              <pre>
                 <code class="language-markup">
                 {`
                <label class="select">
                <select class="selector">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                 </select>
                </label>
                 `}
                 </code>
             </pre>
         </div>
    );
  }      
});
```

[Demo is here.](http://jsbin.com/yocuyaz/edit?html,js,output)

The only shortage is the indent.

Comment: should have marked this a while ago, but this is the way I went

Answer (score 3):

**First:** Use  [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostaticmarkup) to render component to string

```
var inner = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <label className="select">
        ...
    </label>
);
```

**After** Use [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to prettify your string

```
inner = html_beautify(inner);
```

**Finnaly** Insert it to your code as string

```
<code className="language-markup">
   {inner}
</code>
```

**Url**: http://jsfiddle.net/ohwz5ry2/2/

Comment: The result of your jsfiddle demo has no linebreak.

Comment: It's `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` now (import from the `react-dom/server` package.

Answer (score 2):

Just give children like this and it will work like a charm.

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-markup">
        {`
         .ui-datatable table {
             border-collapse:collapse;
             width: 100%;
             table-layout: fixed;
         }

       `}
    </code>
</pre>
```